# How to write lambda calculus terms of haskell functions, such as map?

Tags: haskell, lambda-calculus

I am learning about Lambda calculus in Haskell and I have seen how lambda terms can be written for Haskell functions such as add and succ. Can they be written similarly for higher-order functions such as map?

Is there a method to derive it from the function description in hoogle?

e.g. https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map

Comment: You can use [fixed-point combinators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Fixed_point_combinators_in_lambda_calculus) like the *Y* combinator for recursion, but that would make it quite cumbersome.

Comment: If you are looking for the source code however, at the right end of the function, you see `source`, if you click on it, you can see how it is implemented in Haskell.

Comment: I didn't explain myself well, for example, add can be written  `(λm.λk.λf.λx. m f (k f x))`, can I write a lambda term for a higher-order function such as map in this way?

Comment: yes, and you can thus make recursive calls with the fixed-point combinators. Note however that the above add is a Church-encoding of numbers, not *the* encoding of numbers. Haskell evidently does not use this encoding, but will use numbers as implemented on the CPU with the instruction set available.

Comment: Can you give an example of how you would use a fixed-point combinator to do this?